# Vue property not defined in instance for template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue template that displays a set of tracks, but my site isn't loading. Console says

> Property or method "track" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
> (found in root instance)

I'm sure the issue has to do with parent-child vue instance relationship or something along those lines, but I'm not too sure, since I'm only starting to learn about vue.js

I read over this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events, but I'm having a hard time seeing what the problem is. What's going wrong?

Here's the template in html:

```
<div id="vue-div">
    <template v-for="track in spotifyResults.items">
         <spotify :track="track"></spotify>
    </template>

    <!-- spotify vue template -->
    <script type="text/x-template" id="spotifyResult">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img :src="track.album.images[2].url"/>
            </td>
            <td>${track.artists[0].name}
            </td>
            <td>${track.album.name}
            </td>
            <td>${track.name}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a :href="track.uri">Play</a>
            </td>
            <td><span v-on:click="add_track_to_library(track.album.images[2].url, track.artists[0].name, track.album.name, track.name, spotify, track.uri, none)">+</span></td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</div>
```

And here is the js:

```
var spotify = {
        template: '#spotifyResult',
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        props: ['track']
    }

self.vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-div",
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    unsafeDelimiters: ['!{', '}'],
    components: {
        spotify: spotify,
    },
    data: {
        spotifyResults: {
                items: []
            },
    }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly have you put your `<template v-for="track in spotifyResults...` code?

Comment: @Stephan-v I've placed it within the vue-div

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your component template incorrectly. Vue is attempting to render your `#spotifyResult` template as a `<template>` block.

To use [X-Templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates), you use

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="spotifyResult">
  <tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tr>
</script>
```

This `<script>` tag needs to go in your main `.html` file, **outside the root element**.

JSFiddle Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/7u0aboe6/3/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I made the changes, yet I'm still getting the same error message. I've edited the original post to reflect changes.

Comment: @user2030942 not seeing any changes.

Comment: Check it now. I forgot to save my changes

Comment: @user2030942 as expected, you've put the `<script>` tag inside your root Vue element. Don't do that